# How to make my output return True if a certain criteria is met?

Tags: python, list

So I wrote this code to find whether there is an uppercase letter AND a number in my string or not and here is what I have so far

```
def passwordOK(password: str):
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "1234567890":
            return True
        else:
            return False
print(passwordOK(password='roskaisHsodihf'))
```

but the result only retyrns if **the first variable is modified, so the output only prints True if the first variable is a number or an uppercase letter**
What changes to my code should be made?

**Please do not use import and try to use the least amount of built in functions possible**

Comment: Don't return `False` until the loop is over.

Comment: [return leaves the current function call](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) - also: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @jonrsharpe not quite, I think, since there's `and`, not `or`?

Answer (score 0):

3 issues:

1. You always return from the first loop iteration
2. `if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "1234567890"` does not mean what you think it does.
3. If it did, your logic would still be wrong. A char cannot be an uppercase letter AND a digit at the same time. And if you mean `or`, one of the two still does not confirm the existence of the other in another position.

The logic you need should go along the following lines:

```
def passwordOK(password: str):
    upper = digit = False
    for char in password:
        if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and "1234567890":
            upper = True
        if char in "1234567890":
            digit = True
        if upper and digit:
            return True
    return False
```

If you were to use some utils you could avoid some of the boilerplate code:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits

def passwordOK(password: str):
    upper = any(c in ascii_uppercase for c in password) 
    digit = any(c in digits for c in password)
    return upper and digit
```

Or even shorter, using the test methods:

```
def passwordOK(password: str):
    return any(map(str.isupper, password)) and any(map(str.isdigit, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def passwordOK(txt):
   return True if any(t.isupper() for t in txt) and any(t.isdigit() for t in txt) else False
```

Answer (score -3):

Logical comparisons do not work like you expect them judging by your code. Each part left and right to the `and` keyword will return either `True` or `False`. Therefore you need to repeat the `char` variable to check against your second list of characters like so:
`if char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" and char in "1234567890":`

An non-empty string will return `True` by default in such a scenario.

Edit:
Also you have to use `or` because `and` will only return `True` if both creterias are met. A single char can't be in two disjunct sets at the same time.
An approach here would be to set a variable if either criteria is met and as soon as both ciriterias are met, you return `True`.

Comment: That's only half the answer (or, the question is too broad) - the code will still only look at the first character in the word.

Comment: Also the character isn't ever going to be in both of those strings.